# Twitter - Does the search just suck or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: api, search, twitter

How can search for an old tweet of mine which I know contains the string: "API" within the tweet text?

The tweets(s) in I tried to find are:

https://twitter.com/stuartpowers/status/101507975751012352
https://twitter.com/stuartpowers/status/115850250106834944

with various searches like http://twitter.com/#!/search/realtime/API%20%20from%3Astuartpowers

Thankfully this is easy as hell with python and their API:

```
stu@sente:~$ python
>>> from followers import *  #followers is a wrapper script I wrote on top of Tweepy
>>> api = authorize()
>>> pprint.pprint([(x.id_str,x.text) for x in list(tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline,'stuartpowers').items()) if 'API' in x.text])

[('115850250106834944',
  "I wish Google's gdata API was magically ported to using @kennethreitz 's #requests library."),
 ('101507975751012352',
  'http://t.co/FpCEVa7 looks damn nifty for anyone dealing with APIs: example:     http://t.co/G0Ror3z')]
```

Turns out there were two tweets which contain "API", they're not incredibly old, `2011-08-11 04:19:22` and `2011-09-19 18:10:26`

and I only have 242 tweets total.

I'd hope there was a way for non-coders to find their old tweets, is that not the case?

Comment: Did you try :http://twitter.com/#!/search-advanced

Comment: Yes.  The linked search - http://twitter.com/#!/search/realtime/API%20%20from%3Astuartpowers - was created using the advanced search formfrom the advanced search form.

Comment: i tried different search queries in twitter advanced search and i was dissappointed! however this helped me find your tweets !

http://snapbird.org/ search for the user @stuartpowers : search query api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The search API and REST API are two independent systems. Search has limited history and amount of tweets. REST has better documented limitations: you can't get more than 3200 tweets from one user.

Both APIs cannot be trusted with historic data - you need to collect it regularly if you will be using it.